# Implementing completion handlers for backgroundSession.uploadTask

Tags: swift, nsurlsessiondatatask, nsurlsessionuploadtask

I have (almost) successfully implemented `URLSessionDelegate`, `URLSessionTaskDelegate`, and `URLSessionDataDelegate` so that I can upload my objects in the background. But I'm not sure how to implement completion handlers, so that I can delete the object that I sent, when the server returns `statuscode=200`

I currently start the `uploadTask` like this

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "com.example.myObject\(myObject.id)")
let backgroundSession = URLSession(configuration: configuration, 
                                   delegate: CustomDelegate.sharedInstance, 
                                   delegateQueue: nil)
let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.myurl.com")!
let urlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)

urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
urlRequest.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

let uploadTask = backgroundSession.uploadTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest, fromFile: path)

uploadTask.resume()
```

I tried adding a closure to the initialization of `uploadTask` but xcode displayed an error that it was not possible.

I have my custom class CustomDelegate:

```
class CustomDelegate : NSObject, URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionTaskDelegate, URLSessionDataDelegate {

static var sharedInstance = CustomDelegate()

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {
    print("\(session.configuration.identifier!) received data: \(data)")
    do {
        let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any]
        let status = parsedData["status"] as! NSDictionary
        let statusCode = status["httpCode"] as! Int

        switch statusCode {
        case 200:
            // Do something
        case 400:
            // Do something
        case 401:
            // Do something
        case 403:
            // Do something
        default:
            // Do something
        }
    }
    catch {
        print("Error parsing response")
    }
}
}
```

It also implements the other functions for the delegates.

What I want is to somehow know that the upload is done so that I can update the UI and database which I feel is hard (maybe impossible?) from within `CustomDelegate`.

Comment: Implement [`didCompleteWithError`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsessiontaskdelegate/1411610-urlsession). And if you want progress updates as it goes, you can use [`didSendBodyData`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsessiontaskdelegate/1408299-urlsession).

Comment: Unrelated, but rather than instantiating `NSURL` and `NSMutableURLRequest` and casting to `URL` and `URLRequest`, you should just create the `URL` and `URLRequest` in the first place. The only trick is that since you want to mutate the `URLRequest`, use `var`, not `let`.

Comment: @Rob I have done that but my problem is how to "get out of" the `CustomDelegate` class. If I'm for example in `mainViewController` and I call a function which does the setup of the `uploadTask` then I want to update the UI for example

Comment: You give your custom delegate class some mechanism to inform the main view controller. The typical ways are a "completion handler" closure or protocol-delegate pattern (i.e. 1. have your custom delegate object define a protocol by which it will inform about updates, 2. have its own `delegate` property of that type, 3. have the main view controller conform to that protocol, and 4. when you start the request, set the view controller as the delegate of the "custom delegate object"). Or post a notification.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Rob. Is it possible to use a completion handler closure with background upload tasks?

Comment: No. As [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsession) says, "For all background downloads and uploads, you must provide a `delegate` that conforms to the `URLSessionDownloadDelegate` protocol."

Comment: Ah ok, I'm still a little confused, could you show an example in code how you would for example update the UI from within the `CustomDelegate` class? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're only interested in detecting the completion of the request, the simplest approach is to use a closure:

```
class CustomDelegate : NSObject, URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionTaskDelegate, URLSessionDataDelegate {

    static var sharedInstance = CustomDelegate()
    var uploadDidFinish: ((URLSessionTask, Error?) -> Void)?

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            uploadDidFinish?(task, error)
        }
    }

}
```

Then your view controller would set this closure before initiating the request, e.g.

```
CustomDelegate.sharedInstance.uploadDidFinish = { [weak self] task, error in
    // update the UI for the completion here
}

// start the request here
```

---

If you want to update your UI for multiple situations (e.g. not only as uploads finish, but progress as the uploads are sent), you theoretically could set multiple closures (one for completion, one for progress), but often you'd adopt your own delegate-protocol pattern. (Personally, I'd rename `CustomDelegate` to something like `UploadManager` to avoid confusion about who's a delegate to what, but that's up to you.)

For example you might do:

```
protocol UploadDelegate: class {
    func didComplete(session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, error: Error?)
    func didSendBodyData(session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, bytesSent: Int64, totalBytesSent: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToSend: Int64)
}
```

Then, in your network request manager (your `CustomDelegate` implementation), define a `delegate` property:

```
weak var delegate: UploadDelegate?
```

In the appropriate `URLSession` delegate methods, you'd call your custom delegate methods to pass along the information to the view controller:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
    // do whatever you want here

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        delegate?.didComplete(session: session, task: task, didCompleteWithError: error)
    }
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didSendBodyData bytesSent: Int64, totalBytesSent: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToSend: Int64) {
    // do whatever you want here

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        delegate?.didSendBodyData(session: session, task: task, bytesSent: bytesSent, totalBytesSent: totalBytesSent, totalBytesExpectedToSend: totalBytesExpectedToSend)
    }
}
```

Then, you'd declare your view controller to conform to your new protocol and implement these methods:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UploadDelegate {
    ...
    func startRequests() {
        CustomDelegate.sharedInstance.delegate = self

        // initiate request(s)
    }

    func didComplete(session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, error: Error?) {
        // update UI here
    }

    func didSendBodyData(session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, bytesSent: Int64, totalBytesSent: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToSend: Int64) { 
        // update UI here
    }
}
```

Now, you might update this `UploadDelegate` protocol to capture model information and pass that as a parameter to your methods, too, but hopefully this illustrates the basic idea.

---

Some minor observations:

1. When creating your session, you probably should excise the `NSURL` and `NSMutableURLRequest` types from your code, e.g.:

   ```
   let url = URL(string: "https://www.myurl.com")!
   var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

   urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
   urlRequest.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

   let uploadTask = backgroundSession.uploadTask(with: urlRequest, fromFile: path)

   uploadTask.resume()
   ```
2. You are looking for `statusCode` in `didReceiveData`. You really should be doing that in `didReceiveResponse`. Also, you generally get the status code from the `URLResponse`.
3. You are parsing the response in `didReceiveData`. Generally, you should do that in `didCompleteWithError` (just in case it takes multiple calls to `didReceiveData` to receive the entire response).
4. I don't know what this `myObject.id` is, but the identifier you've chosen, `"com.example.myObject\(myObject.id)"`, is somewhat suspect:

   - Are you creating a new `URLSession` instance for each object? You probably want one for all of the requests.
   - When your app is suspended/jettisoned while the upload continues in the background, when the app is restarted, do you have a reliable way of reinstantiating the same session objects?

   Generally you'd want a single upload session for all of your uploads, and the name should be consistent. I'm not saying you *can't* do it the way you have, but it seems like it's going to be problematic recreating those sessions without going through some extra work. It's up to you.

   All of this is to say that I'd make sure you test your background uploading process works if the app is terminated and is restarted in background when the uploads finish. This feels like this is incomplete/fragile, but hopefully I'm just jumping to some incorrect conclusions and you've got this all working and simply didn't sharing some details (e.g. your app delegate's `handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession`) for the sake of brevity (which is much appreciated).

Comment: thanks a ton, great answer! I have gotten it working except for getting the status code. I think that I'm implementing `didReceiveResponse` incorrectly since it is never called no matter what. Got any ideas as of why? Cheers.

Comment: I'd double check the method signature and make sure that's right: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsessiondatadelegate/1410027-urlsession. Otherwise, I'd suggest posting a new question with a [reproducible example of the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Rob I'm trying to implement a delegate for a download task with a background session but my didFinishDownloadingTo is not being triggered. If you get a chance, I would appreciate if you could take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41488989/using-urlsession-and-background-fetch-together-with-remote-notifications-using-f?noredirect=1#comment70190510_41488989